# Is it okay to list my portfolio website as one of my projects in my portfolio website?

Tags: portfolio

I developed my portfolio website and I kinda want to show it also, in the list of my projects in my portfolio website. I learn some new things when developing my portfolio and I want to show it too. Is it okay to do that, especially when I'm about to look for a job?

Comment: Seems a bit redundant...

Answer (score 3):

If the website was nothing but plain HTML, then anyone who was on the website would already be well aware of what you did. But I'm pretty sure it's not. Maybe the content is generated on the fly from a data store of some kind? Maybe it's responsive design so it looks great on a variety of devices. Maybe you wrote a ton of code, or maybe you didn't write any but you chose a super cool framework that generates what you need without code.

That's what you need to talk to when you list this site as part of your portfolio. Explain a little about how it works, what tech you used, what benefits it provides to use that tech, and so on. Your portfolio doesn't just need to look pretty; it needs to make visitors think "yes! we need this for our stuff!" That means an explanation as well as just images.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is nothing wrong with mentioning it as a project.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously think your website is worthy of attention, so yes. Many people looking at your portfolio will ignore the actual website, or may think 'Nice web site' and that's all.

There is value in specifically mentioning that you designed the website yourself, if it's something you'd like people to know, just as an artist may want to point out that they made the paper the artworks in their portfolio are on.